# Custom Dialog preference with a list view in android

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view, preference, listpreference

I need to add a search bar editText in a list preference. Could anyone please guide me on how to build a custom listpreference and how to integrate that in my xml preference file. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.isys-labs.com/creating-a-custom-listpreference/
have you tried this, It may be use full..

Comment: for simplicity use this: android:widgetLayout="@layout/your_custom_layout"

Comment: down vote !!
for what reason?
I think instead of reading some ppl wants direct answer -_-

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: if you offer a link, try to include the important part in your answer, in case the link gets broken at some point. otherwise this could just be a comment